# How to solve $2\cdot \left( \frac { 1 }{ 3 } \right) ^{ 0.3-x }-4=2$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

How do I solve this equation:

> $$2\cdot \left( \frac { 1 }{ 3 }  \right) ^{ 0.3-x }-4=2$$

I've tried it myself but ended up with x = 0.3, eventhough the correct answer is 1.3
I followed these steps:

$$ 2*(1/3)^{(0.3-x)}-4=2$$

$$2*(1/3)^{(0.3-x)}=-2$$
 $$(1/3)^{(0.3-x)}=-1$$
$$(1/3)^{(0.3-x)}=-(1/3)^0$$
$$0.3-x=0$$
$$x=0.3$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2\cdot \left( \frac { 1 }{ 3 }  \right) ^{ 0.3-x }-4=2\\ 2\cdot \left( \frac { 1 }{ 3 }  \right) ^{ 0.3-x }=6\\ \left( \frac { 1 }{ 3 }  \right) ^{ 0.3-x }=3\\ { 3 }^{ x-0.3 }=3\\ x-0.3=1\\ x=1.3$$

Comment: Ah, thanks! Such a simple mistake to make...